# Why no body answer this question?

Tags: discussion

[Is there a way to hint to query optimizer to MySQL which constraints should be done first?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21608/is-there-a-way-to-hint-to-query-optimizer-to-mysql-which-contraints-should-be-do)

I am just curious. Is there anything wrong with the question? Is there anything wrong with me?

Is it too difficult?

Are people familiar with mysql here?

What can I do to improve the question?

Currently that query takes 1 seconds. I think it's not very efficient yet.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it is because the question is not clear. Sometimes it is because there is no experience related to the database (not likely here given the number of mysql tags I've seen). Sometimes it is because the question you have asked has not been encountered by a fair number of people.

Perhaps you want to offer a bounty on that question. That may raise its visibility and somebody may reply.

Comment: He doesn't have much threshhold to offer a bounty, so that may not be the best suggestion

Comment: I realize that. But sometimes it does help. I have offered bounties with lower reputation before. It bites when you lose it and nobody answers. And it also depends on your subject area. In the case of DB2 I wouldn't offer a bounty until more people are on board for that tag. But if I had an Oracle, SQLServer, or MySQL question, I'd be more willing to offer a bounty. In that sense, he might be wiser to offer the same question on StackOverflow where the number of eyes are higher (sad to say). But I would rather see us grow things here.